# Edit Action not writing referenced ApplicationUser Id to DB in MVC code first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, code-first

I have referenced the ASP.NET Identity ApplicationUser model in all of my tables (LastUpdatedByUser)

When I try to set it as the current user in the Edit method the object property is set correctly but the SQL generated does not include the LastUpdateByUser_Id in the UPDATE query.

Model property:

```
public class ConsignmentStatus
{
//...

[Required]
[Display(Name = "UpdatedBy", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
public ApplicationUser LastUpdatedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

Edit action on controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Code,Name,Description,IsTruckInbound,IsRailInbound,IsVesselOutbound,IsCarImport,IsBulkImport,IsTruckOutbound,NameLocal,LastUpdatedByUser")] ConsignmentStatus consignmentStatus)
    {
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
        var _user = (from u in db.Users
                     where u.UserName == User.Identity.Name
                     select u).First();

        consignmentStatus.LastUpdatedByUser = _user;

        ModelState.Clear();
        TryValidateModel(consignmentStatus);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(consignmentStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
         return View(consignmentStatus);
    }
```

What am I missing? I've tried everything!

Here's the query it generates. Note the missing LastUpdatedByUser_Id:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ConsignmentStatus]
SET [Code] = @0, [Name] = @1, [NameLocal] = @2, [Description] = NULL, 
[IsTruckInbound] = @3, [IsRailInbound] = @4, [IsVesselOutbound] = @5, 
[IsCarImport] = @6, [IsBulkImport] = @7, [IsTruckOutbound] = @8, 
[LastUpdatedDateTime] = @9, [Deleted] = @10
WHERE ([ID] = @11)

-- @0: 'WA' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @1: 'Wagons Arrived' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @2: '1232412312' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @3: 'False' (Type = Boolean)
-- @4: 'True' (Type = Boolean)
-- @5: 'False' (Type = Boolean)
-- @6: 'False' (Type = Boolean)
-- @7: 'False' (Type = Boolean)
-- @8: 'False' (Type = Boolean)
-- @9: '10/01/2019 12:29:32' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @10: 'False' (Type = Boolean)
-- @11: '24' (Type = Int32)
```

Comment: What is the `LastUpdatedByUser` `ForeigKey` name in `ConsignmentStatus` class?

Comment: I haven't got an explicit foreign key declared in the model. I just let code first do it's thing and it did create the DB model correclty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **you said** your `ConsignmentStatus` class does not contain any `ForeigKey` for `LastUpdatedByUser` navigation property, so first update your `ConsignmentStatus` class as follows:

```
public class ConsignmentStatus
{
     //...

    [ForeignKey("LastUpdatedByUser")]
    public string LastUpdatedByUserId { get; set; } // type should be the type of `ApplicationUser` primary key. But I have put it string here.

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UpdatedBy", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public ApplicationUser LastUpdatedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

Now update the database accordingly.

Then Try assigning `userId` to `LastUpdatedByUserId` instead of assign the `LastUpdatedByUser` to the navigation property `LastUpdatedByUser` as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Code,Name,Description,IsTruckInbound,IsRailInbound,IsVesselOutbound,IsCarImport,IsBulkImport,IsTruckOutbound,NameLocal,LastUpdatedByUser")] ConsignmentStatus consignmentStatus)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    TryValidateModel(consignmentStatus);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var loggedinUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        consignmentStatus.LastUpdatedByUserId = loggedinUserId; // assgin userId to `LastUpdatedByUserId` in `consignmentStatus`

        db.Entry(consignmentStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(consignmentStatus);
}
```

Hope it should work for you now!

Comment: I can't access the actual field like that in code first. Only consignmentStatus.LastUpdatedByUser is available

Comment: got it! Well updating the question with more details.

Comment: @EvanBarke check it now! I have updated my answer to match your requirement!

Comment: Got it!! That worked! Thanks a bunch. I wonder why it couldn't figure it out as it usually does.

Comment: Great! It has solved your problem! but I have also simplified the answer more to get the logged In UserId more simply.